# SQLCODE=-30081 Cannot connect to IBM DB2 database with python

Tags: python, db2, database-connection

I am able to connect to DB2 just fine with my TOAD application however I need to be able to connect within python to build some automated reports.

I have installed the `ibm_db` library and I am trying to follow the instructions but I keep getting error `SQLCODE=-30081`.

```
import ibm_db

conn_str = 'database=XXXX;hostname=XXXX.host.com;port=11111;protocol=tcpip;uid=user;pwd=password'
conn = ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Report/MAIN/MAIN.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
 SQLCODE=-30081
```

Looking up `-30081` is not very helpful as it can be caused by a list of things.

I did read somewhere that maybe `ibm_db` is only supported on Python 3.4 and I am using Python 3.6 however I cannot install Python 3.4 on my work PC right now as its admin locked.

Update:

Tested connection using the command line with the 2 different connections options available to ibm_db.

Both connections types:

```
import ibm_db


conn_str = 'database=XXXX;hostname=111.111.111.111;port=11111;protocol=tcpip;uid=username;pwd=password'

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, '', '')
except:
    print("no connection:", ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
else:
    print("The 1st connection was successful")

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect('XXXX', 'username', 'password')
except:
    print("no connection:", ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
else:
    print("The 2nd connection was successful")
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python 3.6.2>python test.py
no connection: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "111.111.111.111".  Communica SQLCODE=-30081etecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10054", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001
no connection: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED" SQLCODE=-30082001
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the correct port? Any details on the error? Can you telnet to that host and port?

Comment: @data_henrik The port is invalid for the sake of the post but the port used in the code is correct as I can connect just fine using my other query tools. There are no detailed errors. That traceback is all I get. I am not able to telnet as it is not a function I am allowed to do at work however I can run queries just fine using my other reporting tools like TOAD.

Comment: Any firewall or Db2 security setting (e.g., trusted context) that filters based on application name or similar?

Comment: @data_henrik not that I am aware of. I have connected to other databases using python such as Oracle with this same PC so I do not believe they are filtering per application. Also I have used power query in excel to connect to databases as well and other applications.

Comment: My python 3.7 works fine with ibm_db on Windows7.  Edit your question to add the version of ibm_db that you are using.  In your exception handler, print the ibm_db.conn_errormsg()  to see the full error message.

Comment: @mao thanks for the info. I tried `conn_errormsg()` with no results.

Comment: Temporarily run your program from the command line (i.e NOT with pycharm).  Show the *code* for your exception handler by editing your question. The subcode/reason-code are essential for the 30081 diagnosis.  If you cannot get that detail, use a CLI trace, refer to Db2 docs for how to enable that. Don't put such new facts into comments.

Comment: @mao ok so it looks like One connections type fails and the other is being denied. I am not sure why its being denied as I can connect through other tools.

Comment: For the first, the subcode 10054 on Windows is CONNECTION RESET so please systematically eliminate the suggestions for this code at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164785

Comment: On additional suggestion: verify that the real connection string is terminated with a semicolon ;

Comment: @mao I am able to connect now. After rebooting my computer the connection started to work. I am not sure what actually caused the problem thought but it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message says:

---

SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED" SQLCODE=-30082001

---

Here is one of good articles for this message:

**Error SQL30082N Reason Code 19 or 24**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-sql30082n-reason-code-19-or-24

Here is snipped, we may need to follow on Windows:

> 4.) If you are on Windows please make sure that the group the user is apart of is added to: "Access this computer from network". To check
>   this please do the following:
>
> Click on Start->Run from the Windows start menu
>   Type "secpol.msc"
>   Go to Local Policies->User Rights Assignments.
>   Double-click on "Access this computer from network"

For more information on this topic please see the "Related URL" for more information

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to access `secpol.msc` on my work computer. My issue has already been resolved but thanks for the info it could be useful to someone who has access to that msc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment too.  I hope that useful.  Thanks.